# Javascript onerror event is not working

Tags: javascript, php, html

i'm making an admin portal where admin can create users,and when they create user they only add their basic details. so when a user logs in to the system he finds a broken image. to fix that i did some digging and found out about `onerror` event in img tag. I tried using it,but it is not working.

my code : `<img src="images/<?php echo $image;?>" onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='/images/abc.png';"/>`

Please help me out here,this is the only task remaining to finish of my 1st project.

Comment: Theres a php function that checks if a file exists. Than you dont have to deal with js.http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you can use PHP to check if the image exists and replace it server-side. To answer your question about the image onerror function, see:
[jQuery/JavaScript to replace broken images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images)

Comment: thanks all,my apologies actually i was watching result on a different page i made for test purpose.My mistake just now i figured it out.